# Why do you need to specify the controller and action in the default route for the RoutesTable in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

Why do we have to specify the defaults for the default route?

This is a normal default route:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Why can't I just do this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Home/Index/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
  );
```

I already specified the action and controller but when I use this way, I get an error. Does anyone know why you have to specify the action and controller in the `default` route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a default set of parameters, how is routing supposed to know where to send this URL?

`/`

The defaults let you do that URL, so it knows to use the 'Home' controller's 'Index' method.

Or:

`/Articles`

In this case, the 'Index' action of the 'Articles' controller would be called. Without those defaults, again, routing has no way to know what to do.